# How to debug python programs with shell scripts in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

How to debug python programs with shell scripts in PyCharm?

I have a shell script which starts a PyCharm program as below test.sh:

```
python scripts/recognition.py @scripts/options/with_bert.opt
```

Then at command line I run:

```
sh test.sh
```

I set the debugger break point even in the first 'import' line of recognition.py, it still doesn't stop when it's run in PyCharm.

Is there a way to debug python in PyCharm when it is started in a shell script?

Comment: How do you normally run python programs in Pycharm?

Comment: Click 'test.sh', then right-click then run 'Debug test.sh', but it doesn't stop at the break point.

Comment: I didn't know you could run shell scripts in Pycharm. Anyway, what about python programs? How do you run them?

Comment: I just run: python scripts/recognition.py @scripts/options/with_bert.opt

Comment: What about within Pycharm? How do you run python programs within Pycharm?

Comment: In PyCharm, you just right-click any .py file then click: Run "test.py" with any command line arguments in Configuration's parameters.

Comment: Perhaps you need to click on `Run/Edit Configurations...` to set up the configuration to supply `@scripts/options/with_bert.opt` as the command line parameter to simulate the shell script. Then right click `Debug recognition...` should run your program with the parameter and break at any break points.

Comment: I tested but it didn't stop at the break point. Isn't this a typical usage?

Comment: This is the usual way to debug programs with Pycharm. Refer to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The debugging method is to **parse out the parameters and environment variables** that passed into Python file from shell scripts, and then **add them to the run/debug configuration** of the Python file in pycharm, **or change and add them to the python file** directly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUJzP.png)

For more details, one can refer to [enter link description here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).